# Website dont work correctly on WebView when touching on item or menu in website

Tags: android, webview

Website  dont work correctly on WebView when touching on item or menu in website

I read the other Solutions ,,, and it,s about phonegap and native app

I need solution For Android Studio My device is Galaxy

```
 05-26 10:57:55.543   E/webcoreglue﹕ Should not happen: no rect-based-test nodes found
05-26 10:57:55.633   V/WebViewInputDispatcher﹕ blockWebkitDraw
05-26 10:57:55.633   V/WebViewInputDispatcher﹕ blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because in some scenarios `WebView` fails to notice that its visible rect has changed, so as far as webkit is concerned the page is still not visible. Thus all touches fall outside of the window, and get rejected.

The cleanest fix is when you know the visibility of your `WebView` has changed (such as in response to a `setPrimaryItem` callback from a `ViewPager`), call

```
webview.onScrollChanged(webview.getScrollX(), webview.getScrollY());
```

You will need to subclass the `WebView` to promote the protected `onScrollChanged` to a public method.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution. Use this in your class that extends `WebView`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

    int temp_ScrollY = getScrollY();
    scrollTo(getScrollX(), getScrollY() + 1);
    scrollTo(getScrollX(), temp_ScrollY);

}

return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```